# Why the scroll bar is missing in Flutter web

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, flutter-web, dart-pub

I have a web page project in flutter but there is a problem.

When I write the page with VScode and run it locally on Google, the scroll bar does not come to scroll down the page.

[image]

The rightmost scroll bar on the pages does not appear when flutter web projects are built.

[image]

What is the reason for this?

Is this how Google developers designed it?

Could it have something to do with the native development environment?

Comment: how we are supposed to debug this from a screenshot?

Comment: this screenshot is an example. There is a scroll bar on the internet pages for us to scroll up and down on the far right. But when flutter web projects are built, this bar does not come up.

Comment: hi ali , did you find the answer of your question ? if you did can you please help me out i have the same problem

Answer (score 4):

You need to wrap your `body` with the `Scrollbar` widget, and do **not** forget to set `isAlwaysShown` attribute to `true`.

```
body: Scrollbar(
         isAlwaysShown: true,
```

Comment: that's right
I think I am constantly developing on MaterialDesign, but on the web side, I need to develop in accordance with the HTML structure instead of MaterialApp.

Comment: Ok, then you can show us some code about your page.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the child with ScrollConfiguration

```html
ScrollConfiguration(
       behavior: ScrollConfiguration.of(context)
                          .copyWith(scrollbars: false),
                      )
```